# jQuery sortable. Sort on click with animation

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list of sortable and by click on a specific button the li element goes up or down in the list. I have already done this, but i need it to go up or down with animation. I guess my method isn't really great for accomplishing this.

Here's the code:

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#sortablemain" ).sortable({
 axis: "y",
    opacity: 1,
    scrollSpeed: 0,
    scroll: true,
    scrollSensitivity: 1000,
    helper: 'clone',
 tolerance: 'pointer',
 sort: function() {
  return false;
 }
    }).disableSelection().on("click",".uk-icon-arrows-v", function() {
        li = $(this).closest("li");
 if ($(this).attr("id") == "up"){
     var liPrev = li.prev();
  if (liPrev.length != 0){
      var liTMP = $('<div>').append($(li).clone()).html();
      li.detach();
      liPrev.before(liTMP);
  }
 } else {
     liNext = li.next();
     if (liNext.length != 0) {
                var liTMP = $('<div>').append($(li).clone()).html();
  li.detach();
  liNext.after(liTMP);
     }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

UPDATE: the HTML is kinda massive. If you wish you can see it here: http://wdgroup.eu/newves/ . Scroll a little down to colored tabs, they are the li i want to animate

Comment: can u put html ? or reproduce in fiddle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it by using css. Added a transition rule to all tabs and by click before deataching and appending I move them

```
li.css("transform","translate3d(0,-310px,0)");
liPrev.css("transform","translate3d(0,310px,0)");
```

and

```
li.css("transform","translate3d(0,310px,0)");
liNext.css("transform","translate3d(0,-310px,0)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using `detach()` which does't add a animation when taking off a element. you can ofcourse use [slideup](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) and [slidedown](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) instead , for toggling the visibility of the element.

or you can just do `slideup(200).detach()` and you will have a animation .

if you want to customize the transition though you can always go for a library like **[TRANSIT.JS](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)** , its a rewrite of how transitions are done in jquery.

Comment: @JurijJazdanov `fadeIn()` , `fadeOut()` ?

Comment: I need to slightly change the position, fade isn't the solution